# Obtener numero maximo y minimo números

Tags: java

Tengo este código de Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));

}

public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
    int numG = 0;
    int numC = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length() ; i++){
      
        if(!((Character)numbers.charAt(i)).equals(' ')) {
            numG = numbers.charAt(i);
            numC = numbers.charAt(i);
            for(int j = 1; j < numbers.length(); j++) {
                if(!((Character)numbers.charAt(i)).equals(' ')) {
                    if (numbers.charAt(i) > numbers.charAt(j)) {
                        numG = numbers.charAt(i);
                    }
                    
                    if (numbers.charAt(i) < numbers.charAt(j)) {
                        numC = numbers.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
    return numG + " " + numC;
}
```

Alguien me podría explicar porque el output si le doy `"1 2 3 4 5"` es `"53 53"` y no `"5 1"`
Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Estoy buscando el número más grande y el más chico del String...

`numG` hace referencia a Número Grande o el más grande..
`numC` hace referencia al más chico..

Gracias

Comment: Hola, Por què "1 2 3 4 5"  debe dar "5 1"?

Comment: perdón ahora lo dejo más claro... yo como inexperto supuse que estoy obteniendo el valor mas grande del String y el valor mas chico..

Comment: Las comparaciones no debes hacerlas entre los de los arreglos sino contra el último número encontrado ya sea el mayor o menor.. Deberías recorrer solo un arreglo e inicializar numG al menor valor posible y numC al mayor valor posible para que se asignen la primera vez que entra al loop. La comparación tienes que hacerla contra numG y numC que son los que contienen el último número mayor o menor según sea el caso.

Comment: La primera vez numG y numC tendrán 1. Luego las siguientes iteraciones la única condición que se cumpliría es la de mayor. En el wte caso 2> 1, 3 > 2 etc numG va tomando los números 1, 2, 3. En resumen compara cada num Ro del arreglo contra numG o numC. En tu código la segunda iteracion de `i` te volante los valores de numC y numG de la primera iteracion.

Comment: Tienes varios detalles, pero uno de los principales problemas es que estas obteniendo el valor del caracter y lo tratas de comparar con un valor numerico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que estas obteniendo el caracter y este lo estas comparando, debes obtener el valor del caracter y esto compararlo para obtener el numero maximo y minimo.

Para que la comparaciòn sea correcta puedes inicializar los valores con los maximos y minimos valores posibles enteros:

```
    int numG = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//Inicializa con el minimo valor.
    int numC = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//Inicializa con el maximo valor.
```

No necesitas tener dos comparaciones para buscar espacios, con una comparaciòn es suficiente:

```
public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
 
    int numG = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//Inicializa con el minimo valor.
    int numC = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//Inicializa con el maximo valor.
                  
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length() ; i++){
      
        if(!((Character)numbers.charAt(i)).equals(' ')) {//filtra espacios 
            
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numbers.charAt(i))) > numG) {
                        numG = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numbers.charAt(i)));
                    }                    
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numbers.charAt(i))) <= numC) {
                        numC = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(numbers.charAt(i)));
                    }             

        }

    }
    return numG + " " + numC;
}
```

---

Otra forma en la cual puedes realizar lo mismo convertir la cadena en un array usando:

```
   String numeros[] = numbers.split(" ");
```

al obtener el array puedes iterar en sus elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a partir de esto realizar la comparaciòn para buscar el valor maximo y minimo

```
 public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
    
    int numG = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//Inicializa con el minimo valor Int.
    int numC = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//Inicializa con el maximo valor Int.
        
    //Convierte cadena a arreglo. 
    String numeros[] = numbers.split(" ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){

             if (Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]) > numG) {
                 numG = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
             }
             if (Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]) <= numC) {
                 numC = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
             }     
    }      
    return numG + " " + numC;
    
 }
```

Comment: Gracias, sabés que si me di cuenta del error... lo estaba corrigiendo y llegué a la misma resolución que vos... pero me encontré con otro problema.. aparentemente el comparador de espacios en la linea  `if(!((Character)numbers.charAt(i)).equals(' '))` no está filtrando bien los espacios... se me ocurrió usar `Character.isDigit()` pero resulta que tampoco me cuenta bien los números...de todas maneras no tendría estar ese filtro si estás usando un array ya separado.. o me equivoco? Me queda la icognita de porque no anda.. pero como lo resolviste anda bien si sacas eso que marqué.

Comment: Creo que el principal probleme es la comparaciòn para realizarla debes usar valores de tipo Int, no Char o String.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede lograr mediante Streams de manera muy sencilla. Para esto consideraremos dos casos:

## El String está limpio

Es decir, estás seguro que tu String cumple siempre con el formato número y espacio.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(highAndLow("32 -85.6 -86 31.1"));
        System.out.println(highAndLow("  "));
    }

    public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
        Set<Double> nums = Arrays.stream(numbers.trim().split(" "))
                .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return nums.size() > 0 ? "Min: " + Collections.min(nums) + "\tMax: " + Collections.max(nums) : "Sin elementos";
    }
}
```

A lo que el output sería

```
Min: -86.0  Max: 32.0
Sin elementos
```

## El String está sucio

Para este caso simplemente limpiamos nuestro String

1. Quitamos todos los caracteres que no estén relacionados con un número, es decir, quitamos todo lo que sea distinto a un signo negativo, dígitos (0-9) o puntos (tomando el punto como marcador decimal)
2. Quitamos los espacios dobles
3. Por cada elemento, verificaremos que tenga el formato de un número real, de lo contrario será descartado

Para ello simplemente hay que añadir al código anterior estas 3 consideraciones, para ello se usará regex

1. `[^0-9 .-]` se sustituirá por un espacio
2. `\s{2,}` se sustituirá por un espacio
3. `[-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)` será nuestra expresión para verificar un número real

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(highAndLow("A fd 113,2 -85.6 -86 32.001 14.32.255.198"));
        System.out.println(highAndLow("A 255.255.255.0"));
    }

    public static String highAndLow(String numbers) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+)");
        Set<Double> nums = Arrays.stream(numbers
                .replaceAll("[^0-9 .-]", " ")
                .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")
                .trim()
                .split(" "))
                .filter(e -> pattern.matcher(e).matches())
                .mapToDouble(Double::valueOf)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return nums.size() > 0 ? "Min: " + Collections.min(nums) + "\tMax: " + Collections.max(nums) : "Sin elementos";
    }
}
```

A lo que el output sería

```
Min: -86.0  Max: 113.0
Sin elementos
```

Comment: Sé que tal vez los Streams aún no sean adecuados para el OP como una respuesta, pero me pareció interesante, por lo que publico esta respuesta para lectores futuros o por si el autor de esta pregunta quiere investigar más acerca de esta respuesta para mejorar profesional o escolarmente

Comment: Está muy bueno e interesante, pero mi nivel no llega a streams todavía, ni los estudié. Los he visto ya pero hasta ahí llegué. Lo tendremos para futuros vistazos..